# How to add onclick to Div with a specific class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a few generated div's on my page listing events on a calender, they all have the same class "fc-event-inner". I would like to add a onclick to these div's but am struggling to get this right.

This is what iv tried, no onclick is added and no errors on page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.fc-event-inner').each(
    function (element) {
      Event.observe("click", element, EventClick);
    }
  );

  function EventClick() {
    alert("You clicked an event")
  }

});
```

This is an example of a generated event div:

```
<div class="fc-event-inner">
  <span class="fc-event-title">Requested<br>by Santa</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest providing a JSFiddle for this, so you can see the examples working.

Comment: No errors on the page? `Event.observe` is not a standard JS or DOM method, and it's not jQuery either. I get the error `TypeError: Event.observe is not a function`: http://jsfiddle.net/JaVBF/

Comment: Thanks some of the answers below are working, Is there no way to also id the div clicked?

Comment: I really recommend to read the [jQuery tutorial about basic event handling](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/). It has the answers to your questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need `each()` to bind event to elements with specific class, just selector is enough. Use jQuery [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) with event delegation it will bind event to those which are generted after the binding code.

```
$(document).on("click", ".fc-event-inner", function(){
     alert("click");
});
```

**Delegated events**

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: I tired this, but it had no effect also no errors on the page.

Comment: Check if you have ".fc-event-inner" instead of "fc-event-inner"

Comment: I have a dot in front of my class, should this be in document ready?

Comment: Is there a way to id the div clicked?

Answer (score 7):

Use the delegate version of `on`

```
$(document).on("click", ".fc-event-inner", function(){
   /// do your stuff here
});
```

This catches the click at the document level then applies the class filter to see if the item clicked is relevant.

### Example JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BkRJ2/

### In answer to comment:

You can access the clicked element via `this` inside the event function. e.g.

```
$(document).on("click", ".fc-event-inner", function(){
   var id = this.id;       // Get the DOM element id (if it has one)
   var $this = $(this);    // Convert DOM element into a jQuery object to do cool stuff
   $this.css({'background-color': 'red'});   // e.g. Turn clicked element red
});
```

*Note: You should never have to run an `Each` in order to catch events on multiple items that have a common class.

Comment: Is the no way to also id the div clicked?

Comment: @Pomster: The `this` value inside the event function is the DOM element clicked. `this.id` is the DOM element id (if it has one), or you can use `$(this)` and do jQuery stuff with the element clicked :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="fc-event-inner">
    <span class="fc-event-title">Requested<br />by Santa</span>
</div>
```

Your JS:

```
<script>   
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.fc-event-inner').on("click", EventClick);

  function EventClick() {
    alert("You clicked an event")
  }
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UBhk9/

**Some explanation:**

Because you are using a class(it may be used multiple times, in contrast to an id) it will work for all the elements with this class name. The `.on` method will attach the event handler(in this example "click") to the selector(the class `.fc-event-inner`). If you want to remove events bounds you've to use the `.off()` method and if you only want to attach the event once you can use the `.one()` method.

Comment: Code without explanation is not very helpful.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm sorry for my (non) explanation. Added some explanation. I've looked at your answers(via your profile), but I think you can't expect that I give answers like that because I'm not yet on your level of programming skills :)

Comment: No worries, that's not what I am expecting :) But *some* explanation is always better than no explanation. I feel like if the answer only contains code, it's like giving someone a tool without instructions how to use it.

Comment: Your right, I will keep that in mind and I do agree that some explanation is required. Otherwise SO will be some kind of code generator. Like the metaphors you use!